# Backpack for Laravel: identifiableAttribute

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm struggling with an identifiableAttribute function in a parent model.

In the child controller, this works fine:

```
    CRUD::field('supporter_id')->  // child column for foreign key to parent
    type('select')->           // the type of Backpack field you want
    entity('supporter')->      // function that defines parent relationship in child Model
    attribute('name_last_1')   // column of parent shown in Select field
    ;
```

Each Address (the child table) is identified by the Last Name of the Supporter (the parent table).

But of course just Last Name isn't good enough. So I added this to the Supporter (parent) model:

```
    public function identifiableAttribute() // for Backpack's dropdown fields
    {
    return $this->name_last_1 . ', ' . $this->name_first_1 ;
    }
```

and eliminated the `attribute('name_last_1')` line from the child controller

But instead of the Supporter field showing last-name-comma-first-name, the Supporter field is empty for each child row. And if you drop down the Supporter field, it appears to have the right number of elements to select from, but they each are blank. So apparently the dropdown is working fine, but it's not getting the identifiable attribute it needs from `identifiableAttribute()`.

I also tried `return 'test' ;` in `identifiableAttribute()` to see if that would change the symptom, but it didn't ... still nothing but blanks.

There must be something I'm not understanding about `identifiableAttribute()` and how to implement it. Can you see where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the questions.

If you would like to concatenate strings, please use an acessor as the identifiable attribute.

In your model:

```php
protected $appends = ['full_name'];

public function getFullNameAttribute() {
    return $this->first . ' ' . $this->last;
}
```

An then use in your field definition:

```php
'attribute' => 'full_name'
```

Hope it helps.

Cheers

Comment: Wonderful! Your approach works great.

Comment: But I still don't understand why the other approach -- using identifiableAttribute() function instead of using an accessor -- didn't work. Even if I botched concatenation, the `return 'test'` trick should have made everyone's name appear to be 'test', shouldn't it?  
  
I'm trying to learn as much as I can about Backpack for Laravel. Can anyone suggest why the approach I outlined in my original post didn't work? Is there something about implementing identifiableAttribute() that I'm not understanding?  
  
Thanks!